Documentar Web API controlador con un metodo POST y dos Rutas
Tengo declarado un controlador con un metodo POST que tiene dos posibles rutas y quiero declarar en la documentación una descripción para cada ruta. Pero siempre me coge la misma descripción "OcasionCoches" para cada ruta.
/// <summary>
/// Producto coches de OcasionCoches
/// </summary>
[Route("Compañia/altaCoche/001-001")]
/// <summary>
/// Producto coches de WebCoches
/// </summary>
[Route("Compañia/altaCoche/002-001")]
public JObject Post([FromBody] JObject v)
{
    if ((string)v["usuario"] == "Clave_Usuario1") 
       return JObject.Parse("....") // Aqui el resultado Usuario1

    if ((string)v["usuario"] == "Clave_Usuario2") 
       return JObject.Parse("....") // Aqui el resultado Usuario2

    return null;
}



Usa controladores diferentes para cada ruta, los controladores no permiten tener mas de una ruta asociada a un controlador

@PsychoMx pero necesito que el controlador tenga el mismo nombre. He pensado crear otro POST con los mismos parametros pero no me lo acepta

A que te referis con que no te lo acepta? el Metodo puede tener cualquier nombre.. la ruta es lo que cambia.. igual, no tiene mucho sentido tenes dos rutas que van al mismo metodo, cual seria el punto?

@gbianchi segun sea 001-001 o 002-001 hago una cosa u otra. Pero eso lo controlo segun un parametro que envio dentro del Json Jobject

Lo que yo haría es que en vez de realizarlo de esa manera los paso como parametros y los manejo dentro del controlador

@PsychoMx como puedo pasar como parametro el 001-001 o 002-001 ? Ademas debe aparecer en la Documentacion como si fueran 2 post no 1 post

Dentro de tu JObject que mandas desde la petición al API y dejas solo [Route("Compañia/altaCoche/")]

Sobre los POST que mencionas se dan cada que realizas la petición, por lo tanto tendrías 2 peticiones una con '001-001' (primer post), '002-001' (segundo post), no habría problema

Si haces dos cosas distintas, son dos controladores distintos... si metiste un if ahi adentro, que obviamente lo hiciste, entonces hiciste dos controladores...

@PsychoMx mira la imagen que he subido, esto creo que aclara mejor cual es mi problema. Necesito que la Documentación que genera Visual Studio de la API me salga asi. Pero en la segunda descripción no me pone WebCoches

Tu imagen no hace mas que aclarar que son dos controladores distintos.. porque querrias hacer uno solo con un if?

@gbianchi es el mismo controlador solo que se puede acceder por esas dos rutas. Entonces dentro del Json con un parametro que envia el cliente  muestro un resultado u otro. Funciona bien solo que al generar la Documentación no se como hacer para que salgan las dos descripciones

Si por supuesto que funciona bien.. pero documentalmente no tiene sentido... lo que estas mostrando son claramente dos rutas, y si el parametro va en el JSON mas a nuestro favor.. en esa caso es una sola ruta que hace dos cosas dependiendo el parametro enviado... seria igual que tuvieras un metodo que haga insert o update dependiendo si esta o no el id.. la ruta es una sola... lo que haga adentro el metodo es otra cosa...

Documentalmente eso deberia ser una ruta que da de alta coches.. y dependiendo un parametro, da de alta un tipo u otro... podrias entrar por cualquiera de las dos rutas (segun lo que decis) porque lo que cambia la funcionalidad es el parametro del JSON y no la ruta... es confuso }

@gbianchi he puesto algo mas de código. Lo que me interesa es hacer esto de alguna manera que en la documentación me aparezca como 2 POST me da igual si internamente lo hago con 1 POST o 2 POST. Los Dos parametros son constantes siempre van a ser 001-001 o 002-001, y mas adelante puedo añadir otro que sea 003-001, 003-002, etc..

Y hace 2 post y van a aparecer dos...

@gbianchi  si hago dos controladores la Documentación me separa los POST uno para cada nombre de Controlador y eso no me sirve.  Si hago un solo controlador y 2 POST ¿ como puedo hacer para que me salga como la imagen y cada uno con su descripcion ?

No se como solucionar tu problema de documentacion.. la verdad nunca me puse a ver ese detalle... pero si mas adelante vas a agregar otras rutas, menos tiene sentido tenes un solo endpoint por cada una de esas rutas.. deberias usar una ruta variable a tu post...

Y de igual forma, si no usas la variable que viene en la ruta, menos sentido tiene tener multiples rutas, solo genera confusion...

@gbianchi hay web apis que estan documentadas de esta manera porque el id del parametro es fijo para cada compañia. No se si cuando han documentado estas APIS usan varios POST o solo uno

Eso yo no sabria decirtelo.. nunca tuve problemas de ese estilo con la documentacion...

Yo tengo la duda de que documentación estas usando, porque la imagen que muestras no se parece al swagger

@Yussef efectivamente no es la documentación de swagger es la documentación que ya viene por defecto en Visual Studio. Visual Studio proyecto ASP.NET Framework 4.8 y Web Api

@gbianchi ya he conseguido como hacerlo, acabo de publicar la respuesta

@Yussef lo consegui

Bueno al final parece que lo he conseguido, lo explico por si alguien le ha pasado el mismo problema.
Lo que tenia que hacer era simplemente cambiar el nombre de cada metodo Post
 /// <summary>
 /// Producto coches de OcasionCoches
 /// </summary>
 [Route("Compañia/altaCoche/001-001")]
 public JObject PostCompañia1Producto1([FromBody] JObject v)
    {
        return null;
    }

 /// <summary>
 /// Producto coches extendido de OcasionCoches
 /// </summary>
 [Route("Compañia/altaCoche/001-002")]
 public JObject PostCompañia1Producto2([FromBody] JObject v)
    {
        return null;
    }

/// <summary>
/// Producto coches de WebCoches
/// </summary>
[Route("Compañia/altaCoche/002-001")]
public JObject PostCompañia2Producto1([FromBody] JObject v)
    {
        return null;
    }



perfecto.. pero fue lo que dijimos de entrada eh... usaste distintas rutas con distintos metodos...

@gbianchi si perfecto gracias por la ayuda. No habia caido que los metodos POST del controlador podian tener distinto nombre con la misma definicion de parametros.
